# Duplicate Rule does not fire for old records

Tags: lightning-experience, duplicate-management

I' am having an issue with Duplicate rule. For some reason, duplicate rule is not firing on old records but works fine for new records. Below is the scenario.

1. Initially, I created a Test User(User1) with a Test role in my org.
2. I created couple of contacts using this user(Contact1, Contact2, Contact3)
3. Once we decided on what roles we will be using, I created roles and assigned this user(User1) to one of these roles. Checked to see if User1 has access to all the records created in Step 2 and User1 has access.
4. Then I created a duplicate rule to block users from creating duplicate contacts if they match certain fields(Name, Email & phone). I checked the option of "Bypass Sharing rules" as the requirement is to stop user from creating a duplicate contact no matter which role created it.
5. I tried to test my duplicate rule and tried to create a duplicate contact of Contact1 with same email & phone. Duplicate rule did not fire and it let me create the contact. Now, we have 2 contacts with same name(Contact1) and also same email & phone number.
6. I tried to create Contact1 again with same email & phone number. This time duplicate rule fired and it pointed me to existing contact. But it pointed me to duplicate contact created in Step 6. It did not recognize original contact created in Step 2
7. Now, I created a new contact(Contact 9) and saved. Then I tried to create a duplicate contact of Contact 9. Duplicate rule fired and it blocked me from creating the contact. It worked perfectly.

As you can see, Duplicate rule is not able to check against the old contacts. Do you have any suggestions on why this is happening. It happens with all the old contacts(Contact 2, Contact 3)

Comment: Do you have any sharing rules in place? After you created the new role and assigned it to the user, did you recalculate the sharing rules again?

Comment: Yes Jayant, I recalculated the sharing rules. But still duplicate rule is not working for old records.

Comment: Can you update your post with the duplicate and matching rules that you have configured?

Comment: Jayant, thank you for your response. We are no longer using Duplicate rules now and using another Application for catching duplicates.